# Not Able to access MySQL data through php function

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, wamp

I've added clients in clients.php sown on the following screenshot:

UPDATE: If I add new client from manange_sale page, The List Shows up soon after!

[image: https://pasteboard.co/GS6N1Zf.jpg]

When I try to access them in another page through this function:

```
function get_client_info($client_id, $term) { 
        global $db;
        $query = "SELECT * from clients WHERE client_id='".$client_id."'";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        return $row[$term];
    }
```

It just does not show any clients list on that page:

[image: https://pasteboard.co/GS6PrpI.jpg]

Please help me resolve this issue.
Note: Same script is working perfectly on Online host but causing issues in localhost.

Rest of the client class:

```
<?php
//Notes Class

class Client {
    public $full_name;
    public $business_title;
    public $mobile;
    public $phone;
    public $address;
    public $city;
    public $state;
    public $zipcode;
    public $country;
    public $email;
    public $price_level;
    public $notes;

    function get_client_info($client_id, $term) { 
        global $db;
        $query = "SELECT * from clients WHERE client_id='".$client_id."'";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        return $row[$term];
    }//get user email ends here.

    function add_client($full_name, $business_title, $mobile, $phone, $address, $city, $state, $zipcode, $country, $email, $price_level, $notes) {
        global $db;
        $query = "SELECT * from clients WHERE full_name='".$full_name."' AND store_id='".$_SESSION['store_id']."'";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

        if($num_rows > 0) { 
            return 'A client with same name already exists.';
        } else { 
            $query = "INSERT into clients(client_id, full_name, business_title, mobile, phone, address, city, state, zipcode, country, email, price_level, notes, store_id)
                VALUES(NULL, '".$full_name."', '".$business_title."', '".$mobile."', '".$phone."', '".$address."', '".$city."', '".$state."', '".$zipcode."', '".$country."', '".$email."', '".$price_level."', '".$notes."', '".$_SESSION['store_id']."')
            ";
            $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
            $_SESSION['cn_id'] = $db->insert_id;
            return 'Client added successfuly.';
        }
    }//add warehouse ends here.

    function set_client($client_id) { 
        global $db;
        $query = 'SELECT * from clients WHERE client_id="'.$client_id.'" AND store_id="'.$_SESSION['store_id'].'"';
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        extract($row);
        $this->full_name = $full_name;
        $this->business_title = $business_title;
        $this->mobile = $mobile;
        $this->phone = $phone;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->city = $city;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->zipcode = $zipcode;
        $this->country = $country;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->price_level = $price_level;
        $this->notes = $notes;
    }//Set Warehouse ends here..

    function update_client($client_id, $full_name, $business_title, $mobile, $phone, $address, $city, $state, $zipcode, $country, $email, $price_level, $notes) { 
        global $db;
        $query = 'UPDATE clients SET
                  full_name = "'.$full_name.'",
                  business_title = "'.$business_title.'",
                  mobile = "'.$mobile.'",
                  phone = "'.$phone.'",
                  address = "'.$address.'",
                  city = "'.$city.'",
                  state = "'.$state.'",
                  zipcode = "'.$zipcode.'",
                  country = "'.$country.'",
                  email = "'.$email.'",
                  price_level = "'.$price_level.'",
                  notes = "'.$notes.'"
                   WHERE client_id="'.$client_id.'" AND store_id="'.$_SESSION['store_id'].'"';
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        return 'Client updated Successfuly!';
    }//update user level ends here. 

    function list_clients() {
        global $db;
        $query = 'SELECT * from clients WHERE store_id="'.$_SESSION['store_id'].'" ORDER by full_name ASC';
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $content = '';
        $count = 0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
            extract($row);
            $count++;
            if($count%2 == 0) { 
                $class = 'even';
            } else { 
                $class = 'odd';
            }
            $content .= '<tr class="'.$class.'">';
            $content .= '<td>';
            $content .= $client_id;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $full_name;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $business_title;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $mobile;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $phone;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $address.' '.$city.' '.$state.' '.$zipcode.' '.$country;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $email;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $price_level;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= currency_format($this->get_client_balance($client_id));
            $content .= '</td>';
            if(partial_access('admin')) {
            $content .= '<td><form method="post" name="edit" action="manage_client.php">';
            $content .= '<input type="hidden" name="edit_client" value="'.$client_id.'">';
            $content .= '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Edit">';
            $content .= '</form>';
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= '<form method="post" name="delete" onsubmit="return confirm_delete();" action="">';
            $content .= '<input type="hidden" name="delete_client" value="'.$client_id.'">';
            $content .= '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Delete">';
            $content .= '</form>';
            $content .= '</td>';
            }
            $content .= '</tr>';
            unset($class);
        }//loop ends here.  
    echo $content;
    }//list_notes ends here.

    function delete_client($client_id) { 
        global $db;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM customer_log WHERE client_id='".$client_id."'";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

        if($num_rows > 0) { 
            return 'Please delete sale invoices, receivings, return invoices, return payments for related client first.';
        } else { 
            $query = "DELETE FROM clients WHERE client_id='".$client_id."'";
            $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
            return 'Client deleted successfuly!';
        }
    }//delete client ends here.

    function client_options($client_id) {
        global $db;
        $query = 'SELECT * from clients WHERE store_id="'.$_SESSION['store_id'].'" ORDER by full_name ASC';
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $options = '';
        if($client_id != '') { 
            while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
                if($client_id == $row['client_id']) {
                $options .= '<option selected="selected" value="'.$row['client_id'].'">'.$row['full_name'].' ('.$row['mobile'].')</option>';
                } else { 
                $options .= '<option value="'.$row['client_id'].'">'.$row['full_name'].' ('.$row['mobile'].')</option>';
                }
            }
        } else { 
            while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
                $options .= '<option value="'.$row['client_id'].'">'.$row['full_name'].' ('.$row['mobile'].')</option>';
            }
        }
        return $options;


    }//vendor options ends here.

    function add_log($datetime, $client_id, $transaction_type, $type_table_id) {
        global $db;
        $query = "INSERT into customer_log(customer_log_id, datetime, client_id, transaction_type, type_table_id, store_id) VALUES(NULL, '".$datetime."', '".$client_id."', '".$transaction_type."', '".$type_table_id."', '".$_SESSION['store_id']."')";   
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        return $db->insert_id;
    }//add log ends here.

    function add_receiving($date, $method, $ref_no, $memo, $amount, $client_id) { 
        global $db;
        $query = "INSERT into receivings(receiving_id, datetime, method, ref_no, memo, amount, client_id, agent_id, store_id) VALUES(NULL, '".$date."', '".$method."', '".$ref_no."', '".$memo."', '".$amount."', '".$client_id."', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$_SESSION['store_id']."')";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        return $db->insert_id;
    }//add_payment ends here.

    function add_return_payment($date, $method, $ref_no, $memo, $amount, $client_id) { 
        global $db;
        $query = "INSERT into sale_return_payment(return_payment_id, datetime, method, ref_no, memo, amount, client_id, agent_id, store_id) VALUES(NULL, '".$date."', '".$method."', '".$ref_no."', '".$memo."', '".$amount."', '".$client_id."', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$_SESSION['store_id']."')";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        return $db->insert_id;
    }//add_payment ends here.


    function get_client_balance($client_id) { 
        global $db;

        $creditQuery = "SELECt * from creditors WHERE client_id='".$client_id."' AND store_id='".$_SESSION['store_id']."'";
        $creditResult = $db->query($creditQuery) or die($db->error);
        $receiveable = 0;

        while($creditRow = $creditResult->fetch_array()) {
            $receiveable += $creditRow['receiveable'];
            if($creditRow['receiveable'] == 0) { 
                $receiveable -= $creditRow['received']; 
            }
        }

        $receivingQuery = "SELECt * from receivings WHERE client_id='".$client_id."' AND store_id='".$_SESSION['store_id']."'";
        $receivingResult = $db->query($receivingQuery) or die($db->error);

        while($recevingRow = $receivingResult->fetch_array()) {
            $receiveable -= $recevingRow['amount'];
        }

        $sale_return_payment = "SELECt * from sale_return_payment WHERE client_id='".$client_id."' AND store_id='".$_SESSION['store_id']."'";
        $sale_payment_result = $db->query($sale_return_payment) or die($db->error);

        while($sale_return_row = $sale_payment_result->fetch_array()) { 
            $receiveable -= $sale_return_row['amount'];
        }

        return $receiveable;
    }//get vendor balance ends here.

    function list_receivings() {
        global $db;
        $query = 'SELECT * from receivings WHERE store_id="'.$_SESSION['store_id'].'" ORDER by receiving_id DESC';
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $content = '';

        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
            extract($row);

            $datetime = strtotime($datetime);
            $date = date('d-M-Y', $datetime);

            $client = $this->get_client_info($client_id, 'full_name');

            $user = new Users;
            $agent = $user->get_user_info($agent_id, 'first_name').' '.$user->get_user_info($agent_id, 'last_name');

            $content .= '<tr><td>';
            $content .= $receiving_id;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $date;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $method;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $ref_no;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $agent;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $client;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $memo;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $amount;
            $content .= '</td>';
            if(partial_access('admin')) { 
                $content .= '<td><form method="post" name="delete" onsubmit="return confirm_delete();" action="">';
                $content .= '<input type="hidden" name="delete_receiving" value="'.$receiving_id.'">';
                $content .= '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Delete">';
                $content .= '</form>';
                $content .= '</td>'; }
                $content .= '</tr>';
            unset($class);
        }//loop ends here.  
    echo $content;
    }//list_notes ends here.

    function delete_receiving($receiving_id) {
        global $db;

        $query = "DELETE from receivings WHERE receiving_id='".$receiving_id."'";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);

        $query = "DELETE from customer_log WHERE transaction_type='Sale Receiving' AND type_table_id='".$receiving_id."'";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);

        $query = "DELETE from customer_log WHERE transaction_type='Receiving' AND type_table_id='".$receiving_id."'";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);

        return 'Receiving deleted Successfuly.';    
    }//delete_purchase return receiving.

    function list_return_payments() {
        global $db;
        $query = 'SELECT * from sale_return_payment WHERE store_id="'.$_SESSION['store_id'].'" ORDER by return_payment_id DESC';
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $content = '';

        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
            extract($row);

            $datetime = strtotime($datetime);
            $date = date('d-M-Y', $datetime);

            $client = $this->get_client_info($client_id, 'full_name');

            $user = new Users;
            $agent = $user->get_user_info($agent_id, 'first_name').' '.$user->get_user_info($agent_id, 'last_name');

            $content .= '<tr><td>';
            $content .= $return_payment_id;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $date;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $method;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $ref_no;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $agent;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $client;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $memo;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $amount;
            $content .= '</td>';
            if(partial_access('admin')) { 
                $content .= '<td><form method="post" name="delete" onsubmit="return confirm_delete();" action="">';
                $content .= '<input type="hidden" name="delete_sale_return_payment" value="'.$return_payment_id.'">';
                $content .= '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Delete">';
                $content .= '</form>';
                $content .= '</td>'; }
                $content .= '</tr>';
        }//loop ends here.  
    echo $content;
    }//list_notes ends here.

    function delete_sale_return_payment($return_payment_id) {
        global $db;

        $query = "DELETE from sale_return_payment WHERE return_payment_id='".$return_payment_id."'";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);

        $query = "DELETE from customer_log WHERE transaction_type='Sale Return Refund' AND type_table_id='".$return_payment_id."'";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        return 'Return Payment deleted Successfuly.';   
    }//delete_purchase return receiving.

    function clear_creditors($amount, $client_id){
        global $db;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM creditors WHERE client_id='".$client_id."' ORDER by credit_id ASC";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);

        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            extract($row);
            if($receiveable == 0 || $receiveable == $received || $amount == 0) { 
                //do nothing.
            } else { 
                if($received == 0) {
                    if($amount < $receiveable) { 
                        $receive = $amount;
                    } else { 
                        $receive = $receiveable;
                    }
                    $query_up = "UPDATE creditors SET
                        received = '".$receive."'
                        WHERE credit_id='".$credit_id."'
                        ";
                    $amount -= $receive;    
                } else if($received != 0) { 
                    $difference = $receiveable-$received;
                    if($amount < $difference) { 
                        $receive = $amount+$received;
                    } else { 
                        $receive = $difference+$received;
                    }
                    $query_up = "UPDATE creditors SET
                        received = '".$receive."'
                        WHERE credit_id='".$credit_id."'
                        ";
                    $amount -= $difference; 
                }
                $result_up = $db->query($query_up) or die($db->error);
            }//main if ends here.
        }//main loop ends.
    }//debts clear ends here.--

    function customers_balance_summary() { 
        global $db;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE store_id='".$_SESSION['store_id']."' ORDER by full_name ASC";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $content = '';
        $grand_total = 0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
            extract($row);
            //getting balance.
            $balance = $this->get_client_balance($client_id);
            $grand_total += $balance;

            $content .= '<tr><td>';
            $content .= $full_name;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $business_title;
            $content .= '</td><td align="right">';
            $content .= currency_format($grand_total);
            $content .= '</td></tr>';
        }   
            $new_store = new Store;
            $currency = $new_store->get_store_info($_SESSION['store_id'], 'currency');
            $content .= '<tr><th colspan="2" align="right">Grand Total</th><th align="right">'.$currency.' '.currency_format($grand_total).'</tH></tr>';
        echo $content;
    }//customers balance summary ends here.

    function customer_ledger_summary($client) {
        global $db;

        $query = "SELECT * from customer_log WHERE client_id='".$client."' ORDER by customer_log_id ASC";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $balance = 0;
        $content = '';
        $balance = 0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            extract($row);

            $datetime = strtotime($datetime);
            $date = date('d-M-Y', $datetime);

            $content .= '<tr><td>';
            $content .= $transaction_type;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $date;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $type_table_id;
            $content .= '</td><td>';

            if($transaction_type == 'Sale Invoice' || $transaction_type == 'Cash Sale') { 
                //Invoice Details.
                $sale_query = "SELECT * from sales WHERE sale_id='".$type_table_id."'";
                $sale_result = $db->query($sale_query) or die($db->error);

                while($sale_row = $sale_result->fetch_array()) {
                    $content .= $sale_row['memo'];
                    $content .= '</td><td>';
                }

                $sale_detail_query = "SELECT * from sale_detail WHERE sale_id='".$type_table_id."'";
                $sale_detail_result = $db->query($sale_detail_query) or die($db->error);
                $invoice_total = 0;
                while($sale_detail_row = $sale_detail_result->fetch_array()) { 
                    $credit_query = "SELECT * from creditors WHERE credit_id='".$sale_detail_row['credit_id']."'";
                    $credit_result = $db->query($credit_query) or die($db->error);

                    while($credit_row = $credit_result->fetch_array()) { 
                        $invoice_total += $credit_row['receiveable'];
                    }
                }
                $balance = $invoice_total+$balance;

                $content .= currency_format($invoice_total);
                $content .= '</td><td>';
                $content .= currency_format($balance);
                $content .= '</td></tr>';

            } else if($transaction_type == 'Sale Receiving' || $transaction_type == 'Receiving') { 
                //Cash receivign.
                $receiving_query = "SELECT * from receivings WHERE receiving_id='".$type_table_id."'";
                $receiving_result = $db->query($receiving_query) or die($db->error);
                while($receiving_row = $receiving_result->fetch_array()) { 
                    $content .= $receiving_row['memo'];
                    $content .= '</td><td>';

                    $balance = $balance-$receiving_row['amount'];
                    $content .= '('.currency_format($receiving_row['amount']).')';
                    $content .= '</td><td>';
                    $content .= currency_format($balance);
                    $content .= '</td></tr>';
                }
            } else if($transaction_type == 'Invoice Return' || $transaction_type == 'Sale Return') { 
                //sale return invoice.
                $sale_query = "SELECT * from sale_returns WHERE sale_rt_id='".$type_table_id."'";
                $sale_result = $db->query($sale_query) or die($db->error);

                while($sale_row = $sale_result->fetch_array()) {
                    $content .= $sale_row['memo'];
                    $content .= '</td><td>';
                }

                $sale_detail_query = "SELECT * from sale_return_detail WHERE sale_rt_id='".$type_table_id."'";
                $sale_detail_result = $db->query($sale_detail_query) or die($db->error);
                $invoice_total = 0;
                while($sale_detail_row = $sale_detail_result->fetch_array()) { 
                    $credit_query = "SELECT * from creditors WHERE credit_id='".$sale_detail_row['credit_id']."'";
                    $credit_result = $db->query($credit_query) or die($db->error);

                    while($credit_row = $credit_result->fetch_array()) { 
                        $invoice_total += $credit_row['received'];
                    }
                }
                $balance = $balance-$invoice_total;

                $content .= '('.currency_format($invoice_total).')';
                $content .= '</td><td>';
                $content .= currency_format($balance);
                $content .= '</td></tr>';


            } else if($transaction_type == 'Sale Return Refund') { 
                //sale Return Payment.
                $receiving_query = "SELECT * from sale_return_payment WHERE return_payment_id='".$type_table_id."'";
                $receiving_result = $db->query($receiving_query) or die($db->error);
                while($receiving_row = $receiving_result->fetch_array()) { 
                    $content .= $receiving_row['memo'];
                    $content .= '</td><td>';

                    $balance = $balance+$receiving_row['amount'];
                    $content .= currency_format($receiving_row['amount']);
                    $content .= '</td><td>';
                    $content .= currency_format($balance);
                    $content .= '</td></tr>';
                }
            }

        }//main loop ends here.
        echo $content;
    }//customer ledger summary ends here.
}//class ends here.
```

The shown screen code where this class functions are being used:
`

```
<?php
  include('system_load.php');
  //This loads system.
  //user Authentication.
  authenticate_user('subscriber');
  //creating company object.

  if(partial_access('admin') || $store_access->have_module_access('sales')) {} else { 
    HEADER('LOCATION: store.php?message=products');
  }

  if(!isset($_SESSION['store_id']) || $_SESSION['store_id'] == '') { 
    HEADER('LOCATION: stores.php?message=1');
  } //select company redirect ends here.


  if(isset($_POST['edit_purchase'])){ $page_title = 'Edit Sale'; } else { $page_title = 'Add Sale';}; //You can edit this to change your page title.
  require_once("includes/header.php"); //including header file.
?>

<?php if(isset($_GET['sale_id'])) { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('reports/view_sale_invoice.php?sale_id=<?php echo $_GET['sale_id']; ?>', '_blank'); 
  </script>
<?php } ?>
                  <?php
          //display message if exist.
            if(isset($_GET['message']) && $_GET['message'] != '') { 
              echo '<div class="alert alert-success">';
              echo $_GET['message'];
              echo '</div>';
            }
            if(isset($message) && $message != '') { 
              echo '<div class="alert alert-success">';
              echo $message;
              echo '</div>';
            }
          ?>
<style type="text/css">
textarea:hover, textarea:focus, #items td.total-value textarea:hover, #items td.total-value textarea:focus, .delme:hover { background-color:#EEFF88; }

#items input[type=text] {width:60px;border:0px;}
.delete-wpr { position: relative; }
.delme { display: block; color: #000; text-decoration: none; position: absolute; background: #EEEEEE; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 3px; border: 1px solid; top: -6px; left: -22px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
  $('form[data-async]').on('submit', function(event) {

    var $form = $(this);
    var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));

    $.ajax({
      type: $form.attr('method'),
      url: 'includes/otherprocesses.php',
      data: $form.serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',

    success: function(response) {
      var message = response.message;
      var client_options = response.client_options;
      var client_id = response.client_id;

      $('#client_id').html(client_options);
      $("#client_id").select2().select2('val', client_id);
      $('#success_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+message+'</div>');
    }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>

<!-- Add new vendor modal starts here. -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addnewclient" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add new client</h4>
      </div>

         <div class="modal-body">
         <form data-async data-target="#addnewclient" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
         <div id="success_message"></div>
            <table style="width:100%;">
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="control-label">Full Name*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" placeholder="Client full name" value="" required="required" />
                      </div>
                          </td>
                            <td>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="control-label">Business Title</label>

                        <input type="hidden" name="add_client" value="1" />
                         <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add client">
                      </form>   
                              </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--add new vendor modal ends here.-->


<form action="includes/process_sale.php" method="post">
      <div class="row">              
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="5">
          <tr>
              <td width="110">Date</td>
                <td width="300"><input type="text" name="date" class="form-control datepick" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Custom Inv#</td>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Custom Invoice number" name="custom_inv_no" class="form-control" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Memo</td>
                <td><textarea placeholder="Memo" name="memo" class="form-control"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th>Select Client</th>
                <td>
                  <select name="client_id" id="client_id" class="autofill" style="width:100%">
                      <option value="">Select Client by full name or mobile</option>
                      <?
                      =$client->client_options($client->client_id); 
                      ?>  
                    </select> 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" href="#addnewclient">Add new Client</a></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
       </div><!--left-side-form ends here.-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function update_total() { 
  var grand_total = 0;

  i = 1;  
  $('.total').each(function(i) {
        var total = $(this).html();

    total = parseFloat(total);

    grand_total = total+grand_total;
    });
  $('#grand_total').html(grand_total.toFixed(2));

}//Update total function ends here.


<?php
  require_once("includes/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Debug for $db. Most probably you don't have the code for creating a db connection in that script file.

Comment: As I mentioned above, The script is complete and working perfectly on Online host. DB connection is fully functional as you can see the first image. Please +1 my post so someone could answer. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate the servers db to your localhost...

Comment: is other db scripts working on this local setup? if not did you checked local phpinfo to verify mysql extension loaded correctly? is that pc running any firewall program thats blocks mysql port? Is there any error message showing? please be more specific to get more accurate answer

Comment: @SyedEkramUddinEmon All other scripts are running smooth exception this particular field. I've Made sure firstly that my all my extensions are working fine. I am adding the rest of this code to help you identify the issue. Thanks.

Comment: then is that query returning any result when you run that on wamp phpmyadmin with a valid client id? also is that $client_id is not null?

Comment: client_id is a primary key in clients table of DB and it can't be NULL and the query is working.

Comment: @user3284463 just for your sake, replaced the DB of localhost with online one. Still no effect. Please vote +1 the post if you appreciate that atleast.

Comment: @UmairRasool You are using WAMP right? So, is the WAMP icon color green at the bottom right task tray?

Comment: @user3284463 Yes All services are functional and the icon is green but is there anything else in your mind which I can configure?

Comment: @UmairRasool Use `try{..}catch(){..}` in your `get_client_info()` function

Comment: Can you please elaborate or make a function for me please? @user3284463

Comment: @UmairRasool Something like [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b22d8a62007b0960fcd6807dd0e0af840b3b246f)

Comment: Thanks for the idea @user3284463 but it didn't change anything or gave any msg, I think there is some sort of configuration required in wamp to access it through DB.

Answer (score 0):

What plattform do you use for the localhost? Online linux server and local a Windows machine? As it is run on the localhost, do you get warnings, notices or the sort? Or even a fatal?

```
<?
                  =$client->client_options($client->client_id); 
                  ?>
```

That looks odd. Why the '='?

Comment: It gave error right below the choose client field when it was like this : <?=$client->client_options($client->client_id);?> I checked the snippet on Phpcodechecker and it did not gave any error. Moreover, I am using wamp server with PHP version. 5.6 and it does give me any error. only thing which might conflict is that I had to assign a port 8080 for SQL local host as port 80 was being used by microsoft. Although your approach regarding this code is right. Please dig in abit more.

Comment: What you must also do, is use an exit after a Location header. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php . In case you have content that needs caching, then you should do this via ob_start and similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally figured how to make it work by the hint provided above. Actually this Syntax doesn't work in this case:

```
<?=$client->client_options($client->client_id);?>
```

The Solution is:

```
<?php echo $client->client_options($client->client_id); ?>
```

Thanks all anyway for brainstorming.